# Why the BootStrap Card component stretch the container size?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

My code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-agk1nr?file=src%2FTest7.js).

According to my code, I have set both cells are 50% height (i.e. CSS class panel),
Why Card component stretches the parent cell height over 50 %?

The Card component working properly in landscape orientation, unfortunately, it does not work in portrait orientation.

I have added the following CSS to control it, however, all of them are not working.

```
height:50%;
min-height:50%;
max-height: 50%;
```

And how I prevent the Card component from stretches the parent cell height over 50%?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please help improve the website and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can opt to assign a height to their parent element.

```
.meeting {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%; /* sample arbitrary value */
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Assign inside a media query as needed